# Why do we differentiate a 4 vector with respect to proper time to obtain 4-velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry, invariants

The coordinates of an event in spacetime are given by the 4-vector $(ct, \mathbf{r})$, where $\mathbf{r}$ is the spacial coordinates of the event. This 4-vector can be seen as 4-displacement of a worldline from the  defined origin of the reference frame we're in at time $t$.

It seems sensible that $\frac{d}{dt}(ct,\mathbf{r})$ should give 4-velocity of the worldline, but instead everything I've read has stated that we differentiate with respect to the worldline's proper time $\tau$ instead, and yet I so far haven't seen any explanation as to why. This answer [here on the Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265594/why-is-speed-defined-as-coordinate-derivative-over-proper-time-rather-than-obser) simply says we do it because it maintains the Lorentz invariant. However, why would proper time be invariant under the Lorentz transformation and other times wouldn't?

Consider $\mathbf{x^\mu}=(ct,x,y,z)^T$, which I differentiate with respect to time $t$ to get $\mathbf{v}=(c,v_x,v_y,v_z).$ Let's check if this is Lorentz invariant:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma & -\beta\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
    -\beta\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    c\\
    u_x\\
    u_y\\
    u_z
    \end{bmatrix}
   =\begin{bmatrix}
    c\gamma-\beta\gamma u_x\\
    -\beta\gamma c+\gamma u_x\\
    u_y\\
    u_z
    \end{bmatrix} =\mathbf{v'} 
$$

$$
(c\gamma-\beta\gamma u_x)^2-(-\beta\gamma c+\gamma u_x)^2=c^2\gamma^2+\beta^2\gamma^2u_x^2+\beta^2\gamma^2c^2+\gamma^2u_x^2 =c^2\gamma^2(1+\beta^2)-u_x^2\gamma^2(1+\beta^2)=c^2-u_x^2 \\
\therefore  \mathbf{v'}\cdot\mathbf{v'}=c^2-u_x^2-u_y^2-u_z^2=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}
$$

Therefore, $\mathbf{v}$ is Lorentz invariant. Why then, do we reject it as the velocity 4-vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why would proper time be invariant under the Lorentz transformation and other times wouldn't?

A worldline is specified by giving the four coordinates $t,x,y,z$ as functions of some other parameter $\lambda$. Each value of $\lambda$ specifies one point on the worldline, and the functions $t(\lambda),x(\lambda),y(\lambda),z(\lambda)$ are the coordinates of that point. The proper time $\tau(\lambda)$ at any point along the worldline is given by solving
$$
\dot\tau^2=c^2\dot t^2-(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2),
\tag{1}
$$
where an overhead dot denotes a derivative with respect to $\lambda$. By definition, a Lorentz transformation is a transformation of $(t,x,y,z)$ that leaves the right-hand side of (1) invariant, so the proper time $\tau$ is invariant under Lorentz transformations by construction. The coordinates are not.

The calculation used in the OP to check whether $\mathbf{v}=d/dt\,(ct,x,y,z)$ is a 4-vector is not a valid check, because it *assumes* that $\mathbf{v}$ is a 4-vector. To determine whether or not $\mathbf{v}$ is a 4-vector, we can  express $\mathbf{v}$ in terms of coordinates, apply a Lorentz transformation *to the coordinates*, and then see what happens to $\mathbf{v}$. When we do that, the problem becomes apparent: the first component of $\mathbf{v}$ is 
$$
  \frac{d}{dt} ct = c,
\tag{2}
$$
which is independent of coordinates. Therefore, a coordinate transformation (specifically a Lorentz transformation) can't change the first component of $\mathbf{v}$ at all, so $\mathbf{v}$ cannot be a 4-vector.

On the other hand, the proper time $\tau$ is invariant under coordinate transformations (by construction), including Lorentz transformations, so the quantity
$$
  \frac{d}{d\tau}(ct,x,y,z)
\tag{3}
$$
transforms just like the quantity $(ct,x,y,z)$. This is why (3) is a 4-vector.

Comment: $$t=\gamma\tau\\\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\gamma\\\frac{d}{d\tau}\mathbf{x^\mu}=\gamma\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x^\mu}$$ Therefore, we are still differentiating with respect to $t$, so the first component of $\mathbf{v}$ will still be unchanged by the Lorentz transformation (since it is a constant irrespective of coordinates).

Comment: @Pancake_Senpai  Your equations are correct, but your last statement is not. The quantity $\gamma$ depends on the spatial components of $d\mathbf{x}/dt$, which in turn depends on the coordinates. The quantity $\gamma$ is affected in a non-trivial way by the coordinate transformation. This is also clear from the first equation in your comment: $t=\gamma\tau$. The quantity $\tau$ is invariant by construction, and $t$ is not (because it's a coordinate), so $\gamma$ cannot be invariant.

Answer (score 1):

The proper time is defined using the invariant interval:
$$
ds^2= (c dt)^2-(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)
$$
The proper time is the time indicated by a clock at rest in the frame of the observer, so $(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)=0$, which makes 
$ds=d\tau$ in the frame where the clock is at an obvious invariant.  Dividing a $4$-vector by an invariant scalar produces another $4$-vector, thus guaranteeing that the $4$-velocity defined as
$$
u^{\mu}=\frac{d}{d\tau}x^{\mu}
$$
has the right transformation properties under Lorentz.

Comment: When we say $d\tau$ is an invariant, what we're saying is that one infinitesimally small interval of proper time is a constant. What does this actually mean, and why isn't an infinitesimally small interval of time $dt$ in frame $S$ or $dt'$ in $S'$ constant also? They are all constant values describing a small change in time experienced in their own respective frames and nowhere else, right?

Comment: @Pancake_Senpai not sure I understand.  $dt$ depends on the reference frame i.e. different observers can measure different time intervals so it’s not invariant.  All observers would agree on the value of $d\tau$ since they would agree on $ds$.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

> Consider $\mathbf{x^\mu}=(ct,x,y,z)^T$, which I differentiate with respect to time $t$ to get $\mathbf{v}=(c,v_x,v_y,v_z).$ Let's check if this is Lorentz invariant:
>
> $$
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     \gamma & -\beta\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
>     -\beta\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & 1
>     \end{bmatrix} 
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     c\\
>     u_x\\
>     u_y\\
>     u_z
>     \end{bmatrix}
>    =\begin{bmatrix}
>     c\gamma-\beta\gamma u_x\\
>     -\beta\gamma c+\gamma u_x\\
>     u_y\\
>     u_z
>     \end{bmatrix} =\mathbf{v'} 
> $$
>
> $$
> (c\gamma-\beta\gamma u_x)^2-(-\beta\gamma c+\gamma u_x)^2=c^2\gamma^2+\beta^2\gamma^2u_x^2+\beta^2\gamma^2c^2+\gamma^2u_x^2 =c^2\gamma^2(1+\beta^2)-u_x^2\gamma^2(1+\beta^2)=c^2-u_x^2 \\
> \therefore  \mathbf{v'}\cdot\mathbf{v'}=c^2-u_x^2-u_y^2-u_z^2=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}
> $$
>
> Therefore, $\mathbf{v}$ is Lorentz invariant. Why then, do we reject it as the velocity 4-vector?

you actually only show that the Lorentz transformation preserves the pseudoscalar product. You do **not** show that $\mathbf{v}$ is Lorentz invariant.

Suppose that a particle follows $\mathbf{x} = (ct, 0, 0, 0).$ Then in this frame you get $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x} = (c, 0, 0, 0).$ In the primed frame you have $\mathbf{x}' = (ct', -vt', 0, 0)$ so $\frac{d}{dt'}\mathbf{x}' = (c, -v, 0, 0).$ But this is *not* the Lorentz transformation of $\mathbf{x}$ which is $(\gamma c, -\gamma v, 0, 0):$
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma & -\beta\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
    -\beta\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    c\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}
   =\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma c \\
    -\gamma\beta c \\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}
   =\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma c \\
    -\gamma v \\
    0\\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting that you have obtained this four dimensional velocity vector as a derivative of the worldline with respect to the coordinate $t$. So when you are changing the ccorfinate system, you are forced to change also the parameter $t$ you are differentiating with respect to. That is going to cause the problems that interfere with Lorentz invariance.